# Movies and TV Site Self-Evaluation review queue not giving 10 question

Tags: support, site-evaluation

In Movies & TV beta Site [Self-Evaluation review queue Apr 2013](https://movies.stackexchange.com/review/site-eval/history?page=3) , i only got 7 question. And as i know everybody gets 10 question. I didn't even skipped any question. So what is the problem with this counter?

Comment: Are you certain there are more than 7 questions to review?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Three of the questions chosen at random for this self-eval were asked *by you*. Since it isn't really fair to ask you to evaluate your own questions, they simply were not shown to you. Since everyone reviews the same questions, that means you're only able to do 7 reviews this time around.

Comment: Is that means they only select 10 question only. I mean i thought they select more the 10 question and assign 10 question from the set to individual excluding his own question. So that everyone one can get a chance to get 10 question.

Comment: Only 10 questions are selected for each review, so that the same questions can be reviewed by everyone.

Comment: ok, thanx for clearing the point