# Why do I see my own answers but not my own questions in a site self-evaluation?

Tags: discussion, beta-phase, site-evaluation

I just found out experimentally that in a site evaluation, you don't get to review your own question. You do however get to review questions that you've answered. The [official rationale](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/174790/movies-and-tv-site-self-evaluation-review-queue-not-giving-10-question/174791#174791) is

> Since it isn't really fair to ask you to evaluate your own questions, they simply were not shown to you.

Site evaluations are about the quality of the answers at least as much as the quality of the question. How does this rationale not apply to answers?

Should users review their own questions as well? Or should users also be prevented from reviewing their own answers?

Comment: So you're saying that you get to review *questions that you've answered?*  That's not a conflict of interest.  Reviewing your own answers would be.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Oh, hello, a visitor from the Trilogy. Welcome to the rest of the network. (Doesn't Programmers get site evaluations?) Site self-evaluations are about whole threads: they evaluate both the question and its answers. So we do get to review our own answers, as part of a thread.

Comment: According to [this post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/161390/102937), Site Self-Evaluations are not shown to graduated sites.  Programmers apparently had *one*, but I never saw it.  You could have avoided "stump the chump" by reminding all of us that this only applies to beta sites.  I'm probably not the only person who has never seen one.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Ah, they did at some point apply to all SE2.0 sites, I hadn't realized that this had been turned back off. Oh, I wish SE would get around to splitting Meta.SO from Meta.SE so we could avoid these culture clashes.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because site self-evaluations haven't existed since 2015.

Comment: @SonictheK-DayHedgehog Then you should vote to close it as "can no longer be reproduced". Closing it as "other" will mark it as "not about Stack Exchange". You can always post a comment manually if you want to clarify why you voted to close, but you should avoid using custom close reasons unless the question actually has nothing to do with Stack Exchange.

Comment: @DonaldDuck I'm well aware. I usually use custom close reasons so that the reason is visible in the close dialog when others review, and so long as at least two others choose the canned reason, it [will show in the notice](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/339401/377214). Most of the time, that happens. Also, it has no bearing for <3k users; to those users, it will just show as "off-topic" regardless of canned reason.